# What is the formula to calculate this sequence?

Tags: c

I've been facing a problem with this particular question in C.
The question is:
Write a program to generate the first n terms in the series --- 2,5,9,..,20,27

I'm stuck in the for-loop part. Like, for other terms
example: series --- 5,9,17,29,45,...
I can calculate the remaining series by the formula:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    a=a+(4*i); //a is initialized to 5
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You add `i` to previous result each time: 2+3=5, 5+4=9, 9+5=14....

Comment: That's not programming, but a simple series riddle.

Comment: You go to OEIS and enter the numbers there: https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C5%2C9&sort=&language=&go=Search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the (i+1)-st element is created from the i-th by adding an increasing number:

- a<sub>0</sub> = 2, d<sub>0</sub> = 3
- a<sub>1</sub> = 2+3 = 5, d<sub>0</sub> = 4
- a<sub>2</sub> = 5+4 = 9, d<sub>0</sub> = 5
- a<sub>3</sub> = 9+5 = 14, d<sub>0</sub> = 6
- a<sub>4</sub> = 14+6= 20, d<sub>0</sub> = 7
- a<sub>5</sub> = 20+7= 27, d<sub>0</sub> = 8
- ...and so on

You can compute this result by incrementing `d` as you walk through the loop, and adding it to the previous value of `a`.

According to the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C%205%2C%209%2C%2014%2C%2020%2C%2027%2C%2035%2C%2044%2C%2054%2C%2065&language=english&go=Search), elements of this sequence could be computed using this closed-form expression:

```
n*(n+3)/2
```

**Note:** The above division always produces an integer value because one of `n` or `n+3` will be even.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you expect?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 2, n = 10;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", a);
        a = a + i + 3;
    }
    printf("etc\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ gcc main.c -o main.exe; ./main.exe;
2, 5, 9, 14, 20, 27, 35, 44, 54, 65, etc
```

Comment: Nice use of zero-based formula `a = a + i + 3`.

Comment: @chux Thanks. Coming from you, that means something.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you're looking for

```
a=2;
n=5; /* to generate numbers up to 27 */

for (i=3;i<n+3;i++)
{
    a+=i;
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

It's n+3 because you would begin with 3 and count n times up from there.

Comment: You should add a space after `%d` so the numbers don't run together.